# JS Snippet reading from local file

Tags: javascript, console, local, code-snippets

I have a JavaScript snippet that was created, saved, and runs exclusively inside Chrome > Devtools > sources > Snippets.  It is a personal code which I don't share with anybody and it runs only on one machine and only inside Chrome Console. Thus, any concerns about security are irrelevant.

The snippet uses a number of parameters that are currently hard-coded as an array within the snippet itself.  I would like to make the code more flexible, by storing the parameters in a text file, then the snippet at runtime should read those parameters from the file and store in memory as an array of strings.

There is no HTML document or  elements, so I don't know how to use File API or fileReader in this case.

Q: how to read a local text file (client-side) using plain JS code that runs inside Chrome Console?

Thanks

Comment: Hello Yasser, you can set your parameters & functions on the window object to reuse them inside an other file, have you tried this way ?

Comment: Hi Tarik, not sure how to do that. BTW the list of parameters could be several thousand lines of text (and is not the same over time). I don't mind if there is  a way to copy them to LocalStorage or any memory in the browser, but the key difficulty is being able to read them from the file.

Comment: `window.foo = fooInstance;`
`window.fooFunction = fooFunctionSignature;`
**those two variables can be used in any script in the current window Yasser**

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader suggests that it isn't supposed to be used at all in the way you have in mind.

My suggestion for a workaround is to run a small webserver that serves the content of the text file, and then use XMLHttpRequest in the snippet to get the parameters from the webserver.

Comment: That is exactly my problem. FileReader does not seem to work. MDN says that it should work in a secure environment, but I suppose running a snippet inside the console is as secure as it can get.

Comment: I could run the code in NodeJS as well and have full access to the file system, but it is a requirement that the code runs only in the browser without without any external resources other than local text files.

Comment: @Yasser Ali Well you would need DOM elements like a file input or a canvas, then it would work because you can show a "upload file" dialog. But without DOM elements and user interaction, I don't see how it could work. Maybe the requirements are.. bad.